# Why does wrapping a function in javascript cause recursion and stack overflow error?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to wrap a list of functions over a callback function. Each of the function in the list takes in the value of the callback and returns a modified value. When I try to do this in a straight forward way, it does recursion, and the stack eventually runs out of space, and throws an error.

I tried solving the problem by using a wrapper function that took in a function, wrapped it with another one, and then returned it, and that solved the problem.

Look at the `subscribe` function:

```
class Observable {
    constructor() {
        this._subscribers = [];
        this._operators = [];
    }
    next(val) {
        this._subscribers.forEach(subscriber => {
            subscriber(val);
        });
    }
    subscribe(callback) {
        if (this._operators.length > 0) {
            let ogCallback;
            this._operators.forEach((operator, index) => {
                ogCallback = callback;
                /** ==== call stack full error =====
                 * callback = (val) => {              
                 *    ogCallback(operator(val));    
                 * };
                 */

                // This works
                callback = ((func) => {
                    const wrapper = (val) => {
                        func(operator(val));
                    };
                    return wrapper;
                })(ogCallback);
            });
            this._operators = [];
        }
        this._subscribers.push(callback);
    }
    pipe(operator) {
        this._operators.unshift(operator);
        return this;
    }
}

const observable = new Observable();
observable.pipe(val => val + 2).pipe(val => val * 2).subscribe(val => console.log(val));

observable.next(5);
```

Why does this happen? They both seem to be the same thing.

Comment: Neither of them does anything (neither callback is called), so I don't see how it could affect the stack size. Perhaps you could include a [mre] that shows how you are calling the functions (and the callback)?

Comment: You haven't declared ogCallback in the local scope, so you only have one ogCallback shared across all your callbacks in the first case. The second one they each have their own one called `func`.

Comment: What is the initial value of *callback* in both functions? On each iteration, it will initially have the value assigned on the previous iteration. You assign that to *ogCallback*, then call that previous value in the "wrapped" function (which is assigned but never called, so is essentially irrelevant). So each iteration gets the function from the previous iteration. Is that expected? It creates a chain of closures (which are never called/executed).

Comment: Sorry for not including the usage earlier. Did that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's from the series of closures created by:

```
ogCallback = callback;
callback = (val) => {
   ogCallback(_function(val));
}
```

*ogCallback* and *callback* are global. After the initial iteration, callback has the value:

```
(val) => ogCallback(_function(val))
```

*ogCallback* has a closure to the global *ogCallback*, so it's value is whatever it was given from the last iteration, as does *callback*, potentially causing circular references.

The second example breaks the closure by creating a local variable *func* in the assigned function expression that is passed the value of *ogCallback* using an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE).

#### Original second example

```
_functions.forEach((_function, index) => {
    ogCallback = callback;
    callback = ((func) => {
        const wrapper = (val) => {
            func(_function(val));
        };
        return wrapper;
    })(ogCallback);
});
```

Comment: I can't say I completely understood the reason. Will need to contemplate some more. But changing `ogCallback` to a local variable, fixed the issue.